# How to update docker daylight saving schedule

Tags: docker, timezone

We have a docker image using America/Sao_Paulo timezone.

Since the government changed the period of daylight saving time in Brazil, it looks like the docker image didn't get the update, even if the linux machine where the docker is installed was.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found something who solve this:

```
apt-get install -y tzdata
ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime
dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

I'm running this first at my Dockerfile.yml. Looks like it's solved.

Comment: The middle line changes your local time zone to `America/New_York`.  You probably don't want to do that if you're in Brazil.  Updating the `tzdata` package should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment variable `TZ` in the docker container to change the timezone.

For example:

```
docker run -e "TZ=America/Sao_Paulo" image_name
```